# unable to resize image properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, uiimage

I am having problem with `UIImage` resizing, image masking is working fine but after applying mask `UIImage` is starched, the problem is with scaling as image is not scaled properly.

```
CCClippingNode *clippingNode = [[CCClippingNode alloc] initWithStencil:pMaskingFrame ];
pTobeMasked.scaleX = (float)pMaskingFrame.contentSize.width / (float)pTobeMasked.contentSize.width;
pTobeMasked.scaleY = (float)pMaskingFrame.contentSize.height / (float)pTobeMasked.contentSize.height;
clippingNode.alphaThreshold = 0;
[pContainerNode addChild:clippingNode];
pTobeMasked.position = ccp(pMaskingFrame.position.x, pMaskingFrame.position.y);
[clippingNode addChild:pTobeMasked];
```

Comment: did you really mean `UIImage` or is that the result of some zealous editing of your question and tags ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of my project I have used below function to resize an image;

```
/*
     method parameters definition
     image : original image to be resized
     size  : new size
*/
+ (UIImage*)resizeImage:(UIImage *)image size:(CGSize)size
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    //here is the scaled image which has been changed to the size specified
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work like a charm. It's similar to the already posted answer, but it has some more options:

```
+(UIImage*)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize
{
    //UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    // In next line, pass 0.0 to use the current device's pixel scaling factor (and thus account for Retina resolution).
    // Pass 1.0 to force exact pixel size.
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```